# Spring boot и чтение с файла. Как можно прочитать file.txt?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-ee

Как можно вычитать файл .txt в приложении на Spring boot (maven)? Проблема в том, что в web-приложениии нельзя указывать путь через корневой диск, типа "с:\programm\lib\file.txt". То есть путь к файлу, используя ResourceLocations "/WEB-INF/lib/" должен выглядеть вот так: "\lib\file.txt". Получается, что единственный правильный вариант чтения файла в приложении Spring boot, это использовать HttpURLConnection. Однако, возможно я что-то неправильно делаю или недопонимаю? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Последняя моя попытка чтения с файла без HttpURLConnection, выглядит вот так:

````
             LinkedList <String> list = new LinkedList <String>(); 
             try {
                 File myObj = new File(DIRECTORY.concat(nameFile));*
                 Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
                 while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                  String text = myReader.nextLine();
                  if(text.startsWith("*")) break;
                  list.add(text.strip());
                 }
                 myReader.close();
               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 System.out.println("An error occurred.");
                 e.printStackTrace();
               }
             return list;
         } ```
````

Comment: В веб приложении, как и в любом другом, можно указывать путь на диске. Главное, чтобы файл там существовал. Какую ошибку вы получаете, когда пробуете читать файл?

Comment: @RomanKonoval А разве не будут потом проблемы с развёртыванием проекта? Там ведь будет домен (сокет-порт) выступать адресом. Так получается? Потом нужно будет заново компилировать код под сервер, например под Heroku или google cloud?

Comment: Тут какое-то недопонимание с вашей стороны. Программа имеет доступ к файловой системе. Если там файл есть, то она его может читать. Не имеет значения, что это за программа. Компилировать специально не нужно. Возможно вы о том, что если у вас в программе зашит путь "C:\programm\lib\file.txt", то это конечно проблема, т.к. такого файла не существует там где вы развертываете приложение. Путь (и имя возможно) к такому файлу должен быть параметром приложения, и в зависимости от того, где вы запускаете вы его меняете. Локально `c:\programm\lib\file.txt` , а на сервере вы зададите другой путь.

Comment: Или вы о файле, который поставляется с программой и является ее частью и не изменяется в процесса работы программы? Посмотрите эти вопросы https://bit.ly/3uSc7T2 и https://bit.ly/3bqIe4m

Comment: @RomanKonoval > "Возможно вы о том, что если у вас в программе зашит путь "C:\programm\lib\file.txt", то это конечно проблема". Да, проблема именно в этом. Возможно имеет смысл прописывать путь к диску в фале application.properties и как-то читать его оттуда?

Comment: Ну так не зашивайте путь в программе. Сделайте его конфигурируемым. Если вопрос в том, как задавать параметры конфигурации в spring boot для разных окружений и использовать их в приложении, то нужно так и сформулировать вопрос.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Согласен, всё логично. Но я тут вычитал в одном умном блоге, что [В идеале ваше приложение, например исполняемый файл jar Spring Boot, содержит все необходимое для запуска, упакованное в него](https://java-ru-blog.blogspot.com/2020/05/spring-boot-deploy-cloud.html).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124245/discussion-between-roman-konoval-and-vitaliy-m-v).

Comment: @RomanKonoval Я что-то не понял как работает чат на stackoverflow (если он вообще работает?), но у меня проблемы не с БД и не с чатом)). Мне нужно вычитывать список названий городов с файла с названием страны. Пример: "\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\countries\United States.txt".

Comment: @RomanKonoval И таких файлов планируется 193шт. Держать эти данные в БД, с моей точки зрения - нецелесообразно.

Comment: Я не предлагаю вам БД. Комментарии не годятся для таких дискуссий. Разберитесь как пользоваться чатом. Задайте вопрос на мете, если не понятно как пользоваться